# .gitignore - directory of ignore files

Tags: git

Is there any way to create a .gitignore folder rather than a file? Such that Git would parse .gitignore/ignorerulesA and .gitignore/ignorerulesB both as ignore files?

I could see this being useful in a scenario where I have two repositories with a non-overlapping structure that I want to merge.

```
repoa
  filea
  foldera
  .gitignore/ignorea

repob
  fileb
  folderb
  .gitignore/ignoreb
```

With this structure I can merge repoa and repob without any conflicts.

If this isn't possible already, would it make sense to request this feature?

I'm not sure if the search results for my question are so poor because:

1. maybe this is just a bad idea
2. I don't have the right search term ".gitignore folder" is just a bunch of instructions on how to ignore a folder. "multiple .gitignore files" just talks about placing .gitignores in different folders.
3. I'm a genus and nobody has thought of this before.

---

Update: Clarification

If we take the two repositories in my example above and apply different .gitignore rules for each repository.

For instance in repoa I want to ignore foldera and in repob I want to ignore fileb. I end up in this situation

```
repoa
  filea
  foldera
  .gitignore
    foldera

repob
  fileb
  folderb
  .gitignore
    fileb
```

Now I want to create repoab.

```
mkdir repoab
cd repoab
git init
git remote add repoa /path/to/repoa
git remote add repob /path/to/repob
git pull repoa master
git pull repob master
rom ../repob
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging .gitignore
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .gitignore
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Essentially every single time I deal with an update to repoa or repob I'm going to have to deal with this conflict, which is certainly not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore directories with `<directoryname>/`.

In your example adding `file*/` will ignore both folders, and there won't be a merge conflict if you try to merge the 2 repo/branch.

Comment: I'm actually looking to have more than 1 .gitignore file, not to ignore more than 1 file from a single .gitignore. I'll edit the question to try and clarify

Answer (score 0):

As you found searching for "multiple .gitignore files", you can put different files in different directories, but Git doesn't handle multiple `.gitignore` files in one directory. In general, Git looks for a configuration file like this in your `pwd` and then crawls up to parent directories until it finds one or reaches the root directory. That strategy doesn't mesh with having a special directory full of multiple configuration files.

Though this won't solve your merging problem (I think you [need submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243909/802618) for that), you *can* set up a global `.gitignore` for things like editor swapfiles that other collaborators don't need to ignore. I have one at `~/.gitignore` and tell Git to read it in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
  excludesfile = /Users/kristjan/.gitignore
```

Comment: Do you think this is an idea worth putting forward to the Git community though? I imagine it would be simple to implement, when Git would normally just read a .gitignore, instead it would check to see if .gitignore was a file or folder, if folder, concatenate all text files in the folder and process them as though they were a file at the .gitignore level. I can't see it as problematic.

Answer (score 0):

> With this structure I can merge repoa and repob without any conflicts.

But you can't.  `.gitignore` files can have exclusions, and even without those it's possible for one repo to expect some kinds of files to be included where the other expects them to be generated (and so ignores them).  Order matters.

You can put your `.gitignore`s in the trees they apply to, `foldera/.gitignore` and so forth. That won't help for toplevel files, but if you've got conflicting specs there you also have conflicting files there, so the ignore mess isn't really the problem there.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. I can replicate my structure and merge the two repositories without merge conflicts. The ignore files simply don't do anything since it's a structure not supported by Git. (the file .gitignore/ignorea isn't treated as .gitignore rules) I'm more interested if there is a simple solution to this conflict. I prefer having all my .gitignore rules at the root and I can't see any drawback of Git supporting a system where all text files in a folder named .gitignore were combined as a normal .gitignore.

Comment: If one `.gitignore` specifies `*.html` because there's some doc-generating system in use, and another doesn't specify anything, what should happen?  If one specifies `*.pdf` and the the other specifies `!imported/*`, and there's a file `imported/frazzlealgorithm.pdf`, what should happen?  What you're asking for is a recipe for _undetectable_ conflicts. That doesn't make them not conflicts, it just makes them conflicts neither humans nor code will see until the consequential damage starts showing up.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'm considering much more complementary repos. I would expect the multiple ignore files to work as an ordered concatenation of them all (including rules for the new repo). If there were conflicting rules in the files it would be up to the owner to figure it out, much the same as if they had to merge two normal .gitignores, only now, if the owner knows there is no conflict, they don't have to handle the merge on every pull. Any files already committed to repoa or repob will not get ignored and only new files in repoab would be subject to this possible conflict.

Comment: If repoa had the rule `*.html` and repob had the rule `!*.html` I imagine it would work in the same way that it would if those rules followed one another in a .gitignore file (which I suspect is, whatever rule comes last takes precedence) which may end up `!*.html`. If there was a way to know the order the ignore files will be processed, it could be determined what the final set of rules would be. After getting this final set of rules you can decide whether or not to overrule anything in the repoab ignore file. (i.e. `*.html`)

Comment: It wouldn't be all that hard to implement, and git is very easy to build. Go for it. I know I've got no interest in this, and I dare say you'll have a lot of trouble interesting anyone else in using it, but if you show up with a working implementation and a workflow that demonstrably benefits from it that could change.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've been looking into it however I don't really know where to look in the Git source to get started. I would give you an upvote but I'm not allowed :( I can somewhat imagine benefits to disjointed MVC suites combining in this manor. Any disjointed repositories that share the same directory structure. My personal situation is combining the codebases of Wordpress and Opencart along with docs/deployment scripts. It seems submodules will likely be the simplest route however. Which means separate public_html folders for one website, which I'm not fond of.